# Marionette v2.2 upgrade error - Cannot read property 'ChildViewContainer' of undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I've started a new backbone, marionette and require project using version 2.2 (i previously worked with 1.8) It seems a lot has changed. I'm getting an error when the browser loads marionette:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ChildViewContainer' of undefined
```

This is my main.js file:

```
require.config({
    baseURL: 'scripts',
    paths: {
        "jquery":  "lib/jquery",
        "underscore": "lib/underscore",
        "backbone": "lib/backbone",
        "marionette": 'lib/backbone.marionette',
        "templates": "../templates",
        "text": "lib/text"
    },
    shim: {
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        marionette: {
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'],
            exports: 'Marionette'
        },
        waitSeconds: 15
    }
});

require([ "app", "marionette"], function(App, marionette) {

    App.start();

});
```

And this is my app.js file:

```
define(["marionette", "router"], function (Marionette, AppRouter) {

    var MyApp = Marionette.Application.extend({
      initialize: function(options) {
        console.log("options.container");
      }
    });

    var MyApp = new MyApp({container: '#page'});

    MyApp.addInitializer(function (options) {
        MyApp.Router = new AppRouter();
        Backbone.history.start();
    });


    // export the app from this module
    return MyApp;
});
```

Comment: sure the reason of this error not in code piece you provided. childViewContainer - is a property of CompositeView, i dont see any what happening beyond Router ?

Comment: Well when adding break points, the error occurred before creating the router or even running the router script :/ It basically throws the error as it loads the Marrionette file which is why i thought it had to be something I did wrong in the main or app file. I cant find any working marionette v2 boilerplates to cross reference with or even just use to get started with.

Comment: Where do you use `{container: '#page'}` option passed to application initialize? I can't see any regions. I saw the same in Marionette's documentation but this is not the way you should use it. You should add initializer which will use that option to attach a new region to `'#page'`.

Answer (score -1):

Just look at your backbone.js file. It's empty. Download backbone.js from http://backbonejs.org/ and replace it.

Comment: My  backbone.js file isnt empty though. It was downloaded from the official site

Comment: please provide any of your `Marionette.CompositeView` code. changes is from item to child

Answer (score -1):

I just ran into this same issue myself.  The issue was multiple instances of Marionette being included on the page. (i had errantly placed a script tag for marionette on the page from cdnjs, as well as trying to include the static file locally via require).  removing the reference to the external JS file helped me...